# Recycle Bin in Android

Tags: android, recycle-bin

I'm trying to implement Recycle Bin application in android, I came across `FileObserver`class to observe all the files, but the problem is `FileObserver` only notifies that file is deleted after file deletion, here is my code snippet

```
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    if (path == null) {
        return;
    }
    //File was deleted from the monitored directory
    if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event)!=0) {
        //Here I want to copy File some where else then I am getting 
        //'File Not found exception' because file is already
        // deleted before reaching this point of code
   }
}
```

Please any body share your knowledge to solve this riddle. This kind of `Recycle Bin` question been asked so many times here in `stackoverflow` and in other sites too, but no proper solutions yet.

There is an application in `Google Play` and the name of that application is `Dumpster` which is achieving the task.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, because me too trying for recycle bin functionality in android

Comment: @SathishKumar No dude, if you find any solution please let me know. I'm still searching for the anser from past 6 months.

Comment: Yeah Sure, I will inform you

Comment: I've queried with some developers, they suggested me to use Shell scripts to accomplish the task. Please go through it as well.

Comment: ok I will go through Shell scripts

Comment: Did you guys find any solution for the same?